# Web Generated Dictionary to CSV file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am tryna collect information from the contact form like (name, email, etc) from website using flask into csv file. This data gets stored into a **mega_data** variable which converts it into dictionary.

Dictionary looks like this; {'Name':'xyz','Email':'xyz','Subject':'xyz','Message':'xyz'}

Here's the code for that:

```
#Dictionary into CSV 
 
def file_to_csv(data):
    with open('database.csv', 'a+', newline='') as database:
        full_name = data['Name']
        email = data['Email']
        subject = data['Subject']
        message = data['Message']
        writer = csv.writer(database2, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow([full_name, email, subject, message])

#Requesting DATA

@app.route('/submit_form', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def submit_form():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mega_data = {}
        data = request.form.to_dict()
        for k, v in data.items():
            mega_data.update({k: v})
        file_to_csv(mega_data)
        return render_template('/thanks.html', name=data['Name'].split(' ')[0])
    return 'Something went wrong, Try again!'
```

But by using this method I would already need to have a csv file ready with specified headers (or keys from the dictionary) which will delimited by any characters.
What I basically want is to be able to define the headers within the function itself which will generate csv file with headers listed along with its related values.

The CSV file should look something like this:

```
NAME EMAIL SUBJECT MESSAGE                                               
abc  abc   abc     abc                                                    
xyz  xyz   xyz     xyz
```

[This is the contact form where from I am collecting data and converting into dictionary, I want to put this dictionary data into CSV file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpTwz.png)

Any help would really be appreciated!!!

Comment: Have you tried using [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)?

Comment: I have tried that as well but I guess we have to manually give key values pairs but in this case I have a dictionary that is web generated and is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Code below would help you

```
def header_present(file):
    # open the file here and check the header, if present or not  return True/False

def def file_to_csv(file,record):
    with open(file, 'a') as f:
        if header():
            csv.DictWriter(f, record.keys()).writeheader()
        json.dump(record, f)
        f.write(os.linesep)
```

Answer (score 0):

1 you can use pandas library to create csv file with columns as you want :
import pandas as pd

2 create a empty dictionary :
mega_data = {}

3 than using full_name you can make a key and enter all values that you want in it :
mega_data[full_name] = [full_name,email,subject,message ]

4 now by using pandas you can give any name to your column that you want :
mega_data_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mega_data, orient='index',
columns=['NAME', 'EMAIL', 'SUBJECT'])

5 after that save this data as csv file and give it any name to that file :
mega_data_df.to_csv('mega_data.csv')
of course there are many ways to use pandas
so, do check out more about pandas library